# How to achieve horizontal scroll widget with snapping and a pointer to show item picked

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I achieve the scrolling behavior shown in the provided image using Flutter? I attempted to use ListWheelScroll but it didn't work for me.

[image]

Comment: @Ramji Yes it helped me achieve my desired result, thanks

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to do that, besides I don't think that's necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [clickable_list_wheel_view](https://pub.dev/packages/clickable_list_wheel_view) package to create this kind of picker. It is similar to `ListWheelScroll` and also detects onTap or Click functions. To understand better about it check out the official web site. I have added a small example which shows how to use it.

Complete Code : -

```
import 'package:clickable_list_wheel_view/clickable_list_wheel_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'List',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const List(),
    );
  }
}

class List extends StatefulWidget {
  const List({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ListState createState() => _ListState();
}

class _ListState extends State<List> {
  final _scrollController = FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: 4);

  int itemLength = 6;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("List"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
                width: 300,
                child: RotatedBox(
                  quarterTurns: 1,
                  child: ClickableListWheelScrollView(
                    scrollController: _scrollController,
                    itemHeight: 80,
                    itemCount: itemLength,
                    onItemTapCallback: (index) {},
                    child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      itemExtent: 80,
                      physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                      overAndUnderCenterOpacity: 1.0,
                      perspective: 0.002,
                      onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {},
                      childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate(
                        builder: (context, index) {
                          return Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: RotatedBox(
                                quarterTurns: -1,
                                child: Text(
                                  '${(itemLength - index) * 5} MIN',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                )),
                          );
                        },
                        childCount: itemLength,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const Icon(
                Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                size: 35,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Output : -

[image]